# Creating a New Variable Based On a Matched Array ID Value

Tags: php, xml, if-statement, foreach, domdocument

I am extracting XML file data using `DOMdocument` and `foreach` loops. The XML file data contains `tag names`, `ids`, `node values` and `attributes` all which are used to extract the data I need.

I am struggling with using an `if statement` to define a variable that I want to echo. The premise of the `if statement` is if a certain `id` equals a certain `id number` then a new variable will be equal to the `node value` of that `id number`. I've put ** ** around the two or three lines of code that are the point of issue. They are at the bottom of the PHP code.

The `if statement` has three possible id values (only one will match) and the `node value` data of the matched id should be set equal to the new variable. If the `<category id="1104"/>` then the node value from `<category id="1104">6-Speed A/T</category>` will equal the new variable `$transmissionfinal`. Thus, `$transmissionfinal` should equal **6-Speed A/T**. Whereas currently, it equals **A/T**.

Any help is appreciated!

*Here is the XML data followed by my code:*

**XML 1**

```
<factoryOption standard="false" optionKindId="7" utf="C" fleetOnly="false">
   <header id="1379">TRANSMISSION</header>
   <description>TRANSMISSION, 6-SPEED AUTOMATIC FOR RWD</description>
   <oem-description sequence="1">6-speed automatic transmission</oem-description>
   <oem-description sequence="2"><![CDATA[With the 6.2L engine on your CTS<em>-V<sup>&nbsp; </sup></em>Wagon, the 6-speed automatic transmission&nbsp;provides smooth, seamless transitions throughout its gear range, perfectly complementing the luxurious feel and responsive steering of a RWD vehicle. Thanks to Performance Algorithm Shifting, you can change the shift points simply by sliding the lever, enjoying a more aggressive progression for an exhilarating experience during sustained performance driving. And, with finger-actuated paddle shift controls on the steering wheel, this automatic immediately converts into a manual.]]></oem-description>
   <category id="1043"/>
   <category id="1104"/>
   <category id="1130"/>
   <category id="1131" removed="true"/>
   <price unknown="false" invoiceMin="0.0" invoiceMax="0.0" msrpMin="0.0" msrpMax="0.0"/>
   <styleId>331824</styleId>
   <installed cause="OptionCodeBuild"/>
</factoryOption>
```

**XML 2**

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <S:Body>
  <CategoryDefinitions xmlns="urn:description7b.services.chrome.com">
     <responseStatus responseCode="Successful" description="Successful"/>
      <category>
         <group id="6">Powertrain</group>
         <header id="15">Transmission</header>
         <category id="1104">6-Speed A/T</category>
         <type id="15">Transmission</type>
      </category>
      <category>
         <group id="6">Powertrain</group>
         <header id="37">Drivetrain</header>
         <category id="1043">Rear Wheel Drive</category>
         <type id="3">Drivetrain</type>
      </category>
      <category>
         <group id="6">Powertrain</group>
         <header id="15">Transmission</header>
         <category id="1130">A/T</category>
         <type id="16">Transmission - Type</type>
      </category>
  </CategoryDefinitions>
 </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php


$xml = file_get_contents('XML/XML 1');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

//Category XML
$txml = file_get_contents('XML/XML 2');
$tom = new DOMDocument();
$tom->loadXML($txml);

foreach ($tom->getElementsByTagName('category') as $catty){
  foreach($catty->getElementsByTagName('category') as $cattydef){
    $cattyid = $cattydef->getAttribute("id");
    $cattyvalue = $cattydef->nodeValue;
    $cattyarray[$cattyid] = $cattyvalue;
   }
  }

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('factoryOption') as $factoryopt){
 foreach($factoryopt->getElementsByTagName('category') as $factcategory){
   if ($factoryopt->getElementsByTagName('header')->item(0)->getAttribute('id') == '1379'){
     $todescription = $factoryopt->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
   if($factcategory->getAttribute('removed')=='true'){
       $tocategory = "";
     }
     else{
       $tocategory = $factcategory->getAttribute('id');
     }
     $toarray[$tocategory] = $todescription;
  }
 }
}

foreach ($toarray as $tocatid => $tomeat){
  foreach($cattyarray as $tcid => $tcmeat){
    if($tocatid == $tcid){
      $toarray[$tocatid] = $tcmeat;
    **if ($tocatid == ('1104' || '1105' || '1106')){
      $transmissionfinal = $toarray[$tocatid];**
    }
   }
  }
 }
echo $transmissionfinal;


echo "<br><br>";


?>
```

Comment: Try `if (in_array($tocatid , ['1104', '1105', '1106']))`

Comment: @NigelRen That works great, really appreciate it! Can you tell me why that works while `($tocatid == ('1104' || '1105' || '1106'))` does not?